# WPF Border shape

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a popup like the one that Lync 2013 has:

[image]

What I´m interested in, is to create a control with that vignette shape.

I have tried creating a UserControl with a Canvas inside and a Path with the shape. But I was not finding Canvas very friendly, so I was wondering if I can achieve this by "playing" with the Border control, so as to put only a border and then a grid inside.

Is this possible? Can somebody help me to be in the right track?

Comment: Have you tried content control instead of canvas?

Comment: No, how do you use it? I wanted something like this <Border with shape> <Grid><Content><Grid/><Border with shape/>. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomBorderStyle.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        LocationChanged="Window_LocationChanged"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1">
            <Button Content="Nice image button" Name="btnThingToClick" Width="100" Height="100" Click="btnThingToClick_Click" />
        </Border>
        <Popup Name="myPopup"
              AllowsTransparency="True"
              PlacementTarget ="{Binding ElementName=btnThingToClick}" 
              Placement="Custom">
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="200" Width="200" Background="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="5" Grid.Row="0" Padding="5">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Text="Some stuff" />
                        <Button Content="Click me" Width="50" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <Path Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Silver" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,-1.6,0,0" Width="25" Grid.Row="1" 
                     Data="M22.166642,154.45381 L29.999666,187.66699 40.791059,154.54395"/>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my code behind for the main window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace CustomBorderStyle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //wire up the popup to the popup placement method
            myPopup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = new CustomPopupPlacementCallback(placePopup);
        }

        private void btnThingToClick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //just invert if it's open or not
            myPopup.IsOpen = !myPopup.IsOpen;
        }


        //this is to position the popup next to the button
        public CustomPopupPlacement[] placePopup(Size popupSize,
                                           Size targetSize,
                                           Point offset)
        {
            CustomPopupPlacement placement1 =
               new CustomPopupPlacement(new Point(10, -200), PopupPrimaryAxis.Vertical);

            CustomPopupPlacement placement2 =
                new CustomPopupPlacement(new Point(10, 20), PopupPrimaryAxis.Horizontal);

            CustomPopupPlacement[] ttplaces =
                    new CustomPopupPlacement[] { placement1, placement2 };
            return ttplaces;
        }
        private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            //if the popup is open when the window's location changes
            if (myPopup.IsOpen)
            {
                //toggle the popup to redraw the location
                myPopup.IsOpen = false;
                myPopup.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will obviously need some nice images to use for the buttons and some better stuff to put in the stackpanel so the popup looks nice, but that should do the job :)
The thing you have to be careful with is the positioning of the popup, this means if you change the height of the popup by adding more stuff you need to change the values of the "CustomPopupPlacement" objects, there might be a nice way to fix this??

Comment: Excellent!! That was exactly what I was needing. Thanks a lot! Simple but clever solution.

Comment: No problem glad to help, let me know if you find a nice way to handle the placement vs size thing :)

Comment: Looks good. But if you move the window, the popup does not move. An idea for this challenge?

Comment: Added a basic method to redraw the popup when the window is moved. It's not the smoothest animation but will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to paste some code that works for me:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Popup Placement="Top" 
           IsOpen="{Binding SettingsVisible}" 
           PopupAnimation="Fade" 
           AllowsTransparency="True">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10" Background="SkyBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Hello, world</TextBlock>
                    <Button Grid.Row="1">Click Me!</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <Path Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Data="M 10 0 L 20 10 L 30 0 Z" Fill="SkyBlue" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding ToggleSettingsVisibility}">Settings</Button>
    <Button x:Uid="Button_1" IsEnabled="{Binding SettingsVisible}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Padding="30, 10" Command="{Binding Next}">Next</Button>
</Grid>
```

My example features two buttons, important for this example is the 1st one (it is part of a wizard-like UI, but you can ignore the 2nd button).

I don't have the ViewModel here, but the mechanism is simple, the *Settings*-Button binds against the property *ToggleSettingsVisibility* which sets the *SettingsVisibility* the Popup binds against. All that is not really important for the example.

The result looks like this:
[image]

Of course, I still have to work on the styling ;-)